# how to get multiple input values in django loop (template) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to get the value of some input field in my django template, the form is in a loop
e.g `{% for p in prediction %} {% endfor %}`.

I have this simple line to grab the id from the input field `let odds = document.getElementById("odds").value`

Based on the fact that i have all these function in a django loop, am i not supposed to get all the odds when i `console.log(odds)`

```
{% for p in prediction.prediction_data.all %}
  <form action="#" method="POST">
     <input type="text" value="{{ p.odds }}" id="odds">
     <input type="number" value="" name="amount" id="amount" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">

    <script>
      function CalculateNewBalance(){
          let odds = document.getElementById("odds").value
          let stake_amount_input = document.getElementById("amount")
                                                 
          console.log(odds);
    </script>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ***id*** use ***class*** or ***attribute*** becouse ***id*** is used to identify unique element in **DOM**. Also you don't have to put your script inside loop and instead of adding form inside loop put input fields.

Your final code will look like this

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  {% for p in prediction.prediction_data.all %}
     <input type="text" value="{{ p.odds }}" class="odds">
     <input type="number" value="" name="amount" class="amount" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance(event)">
  {% endfor %}
</form>

<script>
  function CalculateNewBalance(e){
      let t = e.target;
      let odds = t.previousElementSibling.value
      let stake_amount_input = t
      console.log(odds);
  }
</script>
```

Running code example

```js
function CalculateNewBalance(e){
    let t = e.target;
    let odds = t.previousElementSibling.value
    let stake_amount_input = t
    console.log(odds);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="1.0" class="odds">
    <input type="number" value="" name="amount" class="amount" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance(event)">

    <input type="text" value="2.0" class="odds">
    <input type="number" value="" name="amount" class="amount" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance(event)">
    <input type="text" value="3.0" class="odds">
    <input type="number" value="" name="amount" class="amount" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance(event)">
  </form>
```

Comment: You saved ma a**, thanks alot buddy.

Comment: Hi again, i have a little issue that i have been encountring since that day you helped me. i want to calculate two input fields and add then to the innerHTML, the first one in the loop gets calculated but the other once in the loop does not.

Comment: I made a diffrent question for that, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74873802/javascript-how-to-get-calculate-multiple-input-values-in-loop-using-javascript