# Javascript: how to get calculate multiple input values in loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, javascript-objects

I am trying to calculate the value of some input field in my Django template using javascript (`onkeyup=()`, the form is in a loop e.g {% for p in prediction %} {% endfor %}.

I have this simple line to grab the input values (NOTE: They are in a loop)

```
   let stake_amount_input = document.querySelector("#amount").value
   let shares_amount_input = document.querySelector("#shares").value
```

Based on the fact that I have all these functions in a Django loop, am I not supposed to get all the input field values when I calculate the other objects in the loop?

Based on the fact that I have all these functions in a Django loop, am I not supposed to get all the odds when I console.log(odds)

```
{% for p in prediction.prediction_data.all %}
  <form action="#" method="POST">
     <input type="number" value="" name="amount" id="amount" class="shares" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">
     <input type="number" value="" name="shares" id="shares" class="shares" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">

    <script>
      function CalculateNewBalance(){
          let stake_amount_input = document.querySelector(".amount").value
          let shares_amount_input = document.querySelector(".shares").value
          let potential_win = document.querySelector(".potential-win")

          let potential_win_value = parseFloat(stake_amount_input) * parseInt(shares_amount_input)
          potential_win.innerHTML = "$" + potential_win_value
          
          // if the potential_win innerHTML shows Nan, then i want to change the innerHTML to $0.00, but this is not working too
         if (potential_win === isNan) {
             potential_win.innerHTML = "$0.00"
         }

                                                        
    </script>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**
My template

```
<div class="mid-area">
    <div class="single-area">
        <div class="item-title d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <span>Choose Stake Amount</span>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex in-dec-val">
            <input type="number" required value="{{ p.amount }}" name="amount" placeholder="amount" class="shares" />

            <div class="btn-area">
                <button class="plus" type="button">
                    <img src="{% static 'assets/images/icon/up-arrow.png' %}" alt="icon" />
                </button>
                <button class="minus" type="button">
                    <img src="{% static 'assets/images/icon/down-arrow.png' %}" alt="icon" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p id="error-div" class="mt-2"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="single-area quick-amounts"></div>
    <div class="single-area quick-amounts">
        <div class="item-title d-flex align-items-center">
            <p>Choose <b>Shares</b> Amount</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex in-dec-val">
            <input type="number" required value="1" name="shares" placeholder="shares" class="shares" />

            <div class="btn-area">
                <button class="pldus" type="button">
                    <img src="{% static 'assets/images/icon/up-arrow.png' %}" alt="icon" />
                </button>
                <button class="mindus" type="button">
                    <img src="{% static 'assets/images/icon/down-arrow.png' %}" alt="icon" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="single-area smart-value">
        <div class="item-title d-flex align-items-center">
            <p class="mdr text-capitalize">Potential win</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-val d-flex align-items-center"><span style="font-size: 24px;" class="potential-win">$0.00</span><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting whole form & script inside loop just add input fields inside loop and then either set event on each element inside loop or add event listener programmatically. I'll show programmatic approch.

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
{% for p in prediction.prediction_data.all %}
     <input type="number" value="" name="amount" class="shares" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">
     <input type="number" value="" name="shares" class="shares" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

```js
 let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
function CalculateNewBalance(e) {
    let target = e.target
    let potential_win_value;
    let potential_win;

    if (target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('potential-win')) {
        potential_win = target.nextElementSibling
    } else {
        potential_win = target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
    }

    if (target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('shares')) {
        potential_win_value = parseFloat(target.nextElementSibling.value) * parseInt(target.value)
    } else {
        potential_win_value = parseFloat(target.previousElementSibling.value) * parseInt(target.value)
    }

    potential_win.innerHTML = "$" + potential_win_value

    if (potential_win.innerHTML == '$NaN') potential_win.innerHTML = '$0.00'
}

['input', 'change'].forEach(evt => {
    inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener(evt, CalculateNewBalance, false))
});
```

Here is working example

```js
 let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
        function CalculateNewBalance(e) {
            let target = e.target
            let potential_win_value;
            let potential_win;

            if (target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('potential-win')) {
                potential_win = target.nextElementSibling
            } else {
                potential_win = target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
            }

            if (target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('shares')) {
                potential_win_value = parseFloat(target.nextElementSibling.value) * parseInt(target.value)
            } else {
                potential_win_value = parseFloat(target.previousElementSibling.value) * parseInt(target.value)
            }

            potential_win.innerHTML = "$" + potential_win_value

            if (potential_win.innerHTML == '$NaN') potential_win.innerHTML = '$0.00'
        }
        
        ['input','change'].forEach( evt => {
            inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener(evt, CalculateNewBalance, false))
        }
        );
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="number" value="" name="amount" placeholder="amount" class="shares">
        <input type="number" value="" name="shares" placeholder="shares" class="shares">
        <span class="potential-win">$0.00</span><br />

        <input type="number" value="" name="amount" placeholder="amount" class="shares">
        <input type="number" value="" name="shares" placeholder="shares" class="shares">
        <span class="potential-win">$0.00</span><br />

        <input type="number" value="" name="amount" placeholder="amount" class="shares">
        <input type="number" value="" name="shares" placeholder="shares" class="shares">
        <span class="potential-win">$0.00</span><br />
    </form>
```

**Note:**

> 1. If you're creating application which includes real transactions & calculations of amount you should not rely on client side calculation
>    handle it on server side.
> 2. Don't use ID inside loop it shold be unique

Comment: Thanks alot, your code is working as expected. The only thing is that i have some other elements wrapping my input fields so the `nextElementSibling` seem not to work when i use my template. Please what can i do? I have updated my code to include my template

Comment: Hello @DestinyFranks Where is loop inside your **HTML** code if it's there then add that too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add unique name every time you loop. Variable names and Id's should be unique. For this you have to add counter or unique values. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481619/11282077) for how to add counter.

```
{% for p in prediction.prediction_data.all %}
  
  <form action="#" method="POST">
     <input type="number" value="" name="amount" id="amount{{ forloop.counter }}" class="shares" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">
     <input type="number" value="" name="shares" id="shares{{ forloop.counter }}" class="shares" onkeyup="CalculateNewBalance()">

    <script>
      function CalculateNewBalance(){
          let stake_amount_input{{ forloop.counter }} = document.querySelector(".amount{{ forloop.counter }}").value
          let shares_amount_input{{ forloop.counter }} = document.querySelector(".shares{{ forloop.counter }}").value
          let potential_win{{ forloop.counter }} = document.querySelector(".potential-win{{ forloop.counter }}")

          let potential_win_value{{ forloop.counter }} = parseFloat(stake_amount_input{{ forloop.counter }}) * parseInt(shares_amount_input{{ forloop.counter }})
          potential_win{{ forloop.counter }}.innerHTML = "$" + potential_win_value{{ forloop.counter }}
          
          // if the potential_win innerHTML shows Nan, then i want to change the innerHTML to $0.00, but this is not working too
         if (potential_win{{ forloop.counter }} === isNan) {
             potential_win{{ forloop.counter }}.innerHTML = "$0.00"
         }

                                                        
    </script>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ forloop.counter }}` returns a list of numbers from 1 to number, until for loop runs.

The This would make every id unique and every variable unique. For example, when the loop runs

for first time:

```
let potential_win1 = document.querySelector(".potential-win1").value
```

for second time:

```
let potential_win2 = document.querySelector(".potential-win2").value
```

and so on.